# Why inspect.stack() does not work properly?

Tags: python, stack

I'm trying to write name of the current executed function. But it does not work properly.
When I put `'print inspect.stack()[0][3]'` after the `def func()`, it works, but when I try to put this command after the if, it prints nothing.

```
import inspect

debug = True

def debug():
    print inspect.stack()[0][3]
    if debug==True:
        print "test"
        print inspect.stack()[0][3]

debug()
```

returns `'debug'` but it should return

```
'debug'\n'test'\n'debug'
```

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define the function:

```
def debug():
```

you are loosing the last reference to the previously created variable `debug` from the global scope. You redefine the `debug` variable from being a boolean holding `True` to a function reference. So the condition `debug==True` is not met (because `debug` is a function now, not a boolean). And thus only the first `print` statement works (see [an illustrative demo](http://ideone.com/DyUfGE)).

This will work as intended, for example:

```
import inspect

debug = True

def f():
    print inspect.stack()[0][3]
    if debug==True:
        print "test"
        print inspect.stack()[0][3]

f()
```

This is a common mistake in Python, especially from people used to other languages, in which function names are treated in a special way. In Python they are not - after you define a function, you can use its name as any other variable. Which has many advantages, but as seen here sometimes can be confusing.

Answer (score 0):

In python 3 and hight you need to use print () if. It becomes a syntax error and won't print any thing if you don't have the ()

Comment: The OP says that the code runs without errors, so obviously this is not about Python 3.